# PHP Static Properties, Inheritance, and the self keyword

Tags: php, static-methods

This doesn't make sense to me:

```
class A {
    public static $value = "a";
    public static function get_value(){
        return self::$value;
    }
}

echo A::$value;       // a, this makes sense
echo A::get_value();  // a, this makes sense

class B extends A {
    public static $value = "b";
}

echo B::$value;       // b, this makes sense
echo B::get_value();  // a?  :(
```

Why doesn't the `self` pointer work as expected, similar to `this`?  Is there another keyword that could be used to accomplish this?

If I add the static function to class B, it now works as expected.

```
class B extends A {
    public static $value = "b";
    public static function get_value(){
        return self::$value;
    }
}

echo B::get_value();  // b  :)
```

If the method contained more than 1 line, it wouldn't make sense to copy+paste this functionality and manage it in 2 locations...

Comment: try the `static::` keyword instead of `self::`

Comment: I asked this [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174496/extending-static-classes-in-php-avoiding-sharing-variables-for-multiple-classe) a while ago. Perhaps you can use some of the responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late Static binding:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

> late static bindings work by storing the class named in the last "non-forwarding call".

try using `static::` keyword instead of `self::` in your example.

Comment: Ok, cool.  This is confusing.  I would have thought they would make `self` work as `static` does, and then you can just use the precise class name (`A::` instead of `self::`) if you needed to explicitly reference THIS class no matter what.

Comment: The `self` keyword does not follow the rules of inheritance. `self` always resolves to the class in which it is used at runtime: if you make a method in a parent class and call it from a child class, `self` will not reference the child as you saw :)

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035799/php-when-would-you-need-the-self-keyword