# PHP: When would you need the self:: keyword?

Tags: php, static-methods

I just asked [this question about the `self::` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035666/php-static-properties-inheritance-and-the-self-keyword) and didn't realize the `static::` keyword existed.

It seems to me that you could use `ClassName::` if you needed to reference a particular class explicitly, and otherwise you'd want `self::` to mean the class that called the method.  I'm trying to think of an example of when you would need `self::` where you couldn't just use `ClassName::`.

**Could you replace all occurrences of `self::` with `ClassName::`, where ClassName is the name of the class enclosure that its found in?**  Not that it'd be better or even equivalent semantically, but more functionally speaking...

Comment: As you say, `self::` references the class the method is in directly, `ClassName::` is probably a less efficient way of doing it. I guess it would be like linking images on your own server via a proxy

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718808/php-can-static-replace-self?rq=1) sort of addresses the issue of why you would use `static`, but I'm still looking for why you would need `self`.

Comment: The only (?) "useful" usage for it is when you address class constants. In all other cases it's a sign that you must be doing something wrong. PS: oooops, it's 1 year old answer lol

Comment: It's useful when you want to have a method call it's own class's class constant or static method, rather than a child's class constant or static method.

Answer (score 0):

`self` forwards static calls, while `ClassName` does not, in other words: it resolves to the current class instance.

There may be some cases where you want to reference to the current instance and not an extended instance of the class.

This only really matters for late static binding, seen in PHP 5.3 and up, and why the `static` keyword was introduced.

Comment: what do you mean forwards static calls?  Can you give an example?

Comment: By forwarding static calls, I mean resolving the static method to the current class. Your example in your previous question should answer be sufficient, but I can go into greater depth?

Comment: I would explain the previous example as:  `self::` did NOT forward static calls...  `static::` does.  So I think I have this concept confused.

Comment: Ah right - basically, what I'm trying to say is that `self::` refers to the current instance of the class. `static::` refers to the latest instance, if extended. If `MyClassName::` was used instead of `self::` it would always resolve to that class instance. I'll try to write up a code example and stick it in the answer.

Comment: Does this have to do with using `self::` in a non-static function?

Comment: Fixed typo on website, found another. Also, "Does this have to do with using `self::` in a non-static function?" ; `self::` is a static resolver - unless I misunderstood your question?

Comment: `public static function` is called with `A::func()`.  `public function` is called with `$a = new A(); $a->func()`.  I'm not really sure how `self` and `static` differ when used in either of these contexts.  In my simple example, I can't see a difference, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I'm still writing the code, however in your case, it doesn't really matter whichever is used: they will both resolve to the same class.

Comment: I'm sensing that `self::` is equivalent to using `ClassName::`.  If this isn't the case, hopefully you can show me why

Comment: In most cases, `self::` behaves exactly like `ClassName::`. `self::` exists so that you don't have to explicitly reference the class name when calling a method within the same class, it's only downside is resolved by late static binding; it references its class only.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer: Yes**

I was curious if this would be affected by namespace changes, inheritance or protected status on functions, but it is not. I can't think of anything else that could affect it.

I think `self` is better than `ClassName` simply because it continues to work if you change the class name on the enclosing class or paste the code into a new class.

Proof:

```
namespace Foo;

Class B{
    protected static function printOut()
    {
        echo "Defined in Foo\B name: ".__CLASS__."\n";
    }
}

Class A extends B{
    public static function testClassName(){
        A::printOut();
    }
    public static function testSelf(){
        self::printOut();
    }
    public static function testStatic(){
        static::printOut();
    }
}

namespace Bar;
use Foo\A as B;

Class A extends B{
    protected static function printOut(){
        echo "Defined in Bar\A name: ".__CLASS__."\n";
    }
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B();
$a->testClassname();    //Defined in Foo\B name: Foo\B
$a->testSelf();     //Defined in Foo\B name: Foo\B
$a->testStatic();       //Defined in Bar\A name: Bar\A
$b->testClassname();    //Defined in Foo\B name: Foo\B
$b->testSelf();     //Defined in Foo\B name: Foo\B
$b->testStatic();       //Defined in Foo\B name: Foo\B
```

As you can see, the only time Bar\A->printOut() is called is when you use `static` in Foo\A

Answer (score 0):

I probably describe `self::` as to ignore class being overwritten or polymorphic as it will always use the parent class even it has been overwritten.

```
class A{
  public function foo(){
    echo "hello Mike";
  }
}

class B extends A{
  public function foo(){
    echo "this will be ignore";
  }
}

$tryThis = new B();
$tryThis->foo();

// Above will print out 
// Hello Mike
```

Comment: the question was not "what is self::" but "is there any difference between "self::" and "ClassName::"